# How to obtain values above A9999 in MS Access 97 frontend with a MySQL V5.2 backend?

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have inherited a database which is an MS Access 97 frontend with a MySQL V5.2 backend. In MySQL I have a table with a Primary Key field set at VarChar (50).  This was setup because our reporting system uses an alpha numeric identification.  The same field in the linked Access table is set at text.  At present, I have a query which returns new sequential values over a set value (eg) >S/1234 to generate values which are then added to the above table.  The users then use these values to print a series sequentially numbered reports.  However, I have now come to value S/9999 and users can no longer use the query to obtain values > S/9999.  Any ideas of how to solve this problem would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I guess the answer lies in the query. Show it and tell us what you have tried and what problems you met. Welcome to SO

Comment: The query is very simple. SELECT StTbl.Std, StTbl.lab_ number, StTbl.gr_numb, StTbl.rig_number, StTbl.comments, StTbl.FailureCode FROM StTbl WHERE (((StTbl.[lab_ number])>="S/9999")) ORDER BY StTbl.[lab_ number];